# NumExpr: How to get variables inside expression

Tags: numexpr

I can evaluate an expression in NumExpr like this

```
numexpr.evaluate('17 == b', local_dict={'b': 17})
```

How can I get list of variable inside and expression like `'17 == b'` then I will get `['b']`

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it can be done in a simpler way, but this works for me

```
import numexpr.necompiler as nec
print map(lambda x: x.value, nec.typeCompileAst(nec.expressionToAST(nec.stringToExpression(ex, {}, {}))).allOf('variable'))
```